# How do I setup a mock that dynamically returns results based on a parameter's value?

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to test that an API controller method only returns users (plus some additional states which aren't relevant here) which match based on `Name` where `Name = FirstName + ' ' + LastName`.

I have a repository which exposes a `GetUsersByName(name)` method. I want to mock up a setup for that repository method which will return a `List<UserModel>` containing users which match the name criteria from some stubbed list of users (`this.testUsers`).

I've tried the following:

```
this.mockUserReposiotry.Setup(r => r.GetAllUsersByName(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(this.mockUtilities.MockUpUserModel(this.testUsers).Where(u => string.Concat(
        u.firstName, " ", u.lastName)
        .ToLower().Contains() );
```

but I don't know how to tie the Contains clause back to the `IsAny<string>` that I'm telling moq to match on.

Is this possible? I suspect that I need to provide IsAny with a parameter, but I can't find any similar examples.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, that you really need to mock this that way. Is there vital logic in your API controller, that depends on data that is returned by your repository? E.g. if repository returns data, that does not fit the condition, do you handle it in API controller?

Comment: @NKosi's answer below is correct, but as a rule of thumb you should avoid too much logic within a mocked behaviour. I would return arbitrary values from the SetUp and assert based on those values. Just a thought I don't know your actual scenario.

Comment: @Nasmi Sabeer Generally I'd agree, but this specific method must return values based on specific criteria. If I don't define those criteria beforehand, I can't be certain that they'll be present in all of the variations I need when the test is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can use `Returns<string>` which

> Specifies a function that will calculate the value to return from the method, **retrieving the arguments for the invocation**

```
this.mockUserReposiotry.Setup(r => r.GetAllUsersByName(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns<string>(originalParameter => this.mockUtilities.MockUpUserModel(this.testUsers).Where(u => string.Concat(
        u.firstName, " ", u.lastName)
        .ToLower().Contains(originalParameter) );
```

**Long Answer**

I was able to construct an example test to recreate what you are after.

```
[TestClass]
public class DynamicResultsTests {
    List<UserModel> testUsers = new List<UserModel>();
    string[] names = new[] { "John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Jack Sprat", "John Smith", "Mary Jane" };

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init() {
        testUsers = names.Select(n => {
            var tokens = n.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            return new UserModel { firstName = tokens[0], lastName = tokens[1] };
        }).ToList();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_ShouldDynamicallyReturnResultsBasedOnParameterValue() {
        //Arrange
        string parameterValue = "john";

        Func<string, UserModel, bool> predicate = (s, u) => string
                .Join(" ", u.firstName, u.lastName)
                .IndexOf(s, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;

        Func<string, List<UserModel>> valueFunction = s =>
            this.testUsers.Where(u => predicate(s, u)).ToList();

        var mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        mockUserRepository
            .Setup(r => r.GetAllUsersByName(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns<string>(valueFunction);

        var repository = mockUserRepository.Object;

        //Act
        var users = repository.GetAllUsersByName(parameterValue);

        //Assert (There should be 2 results that match john)
        users.Should().NotBeNull();
        users.Should().NotBeEmpty();
        users.Count().Should().Be(2);
    }

    public interface IUserRepository {
        List<UserModel> GetAllUsersByName(string name);
    }

    public class UserModel {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. I knew I was close, but I needed those final two pieces. Thanks.